# VBA; Multiple footer and header allignment, How can I allgine left Center and right footer?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, ms-word, ms-office

I know that there are codes like:

```
 With ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  .Text = myFooterValue1
  .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignPageNumberLeft
  .Font.Size = 10 'size 10 font
 End With
```

But I want to add, left (company name) Right (Date) and Middle the page number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with TabStops.

You need to work out the width of the page (minus the margins), add a center and right TabStop and separate your values by tabs.

```
Sub insertFooters()

    Dim pageWidth As Double, section As section

    For Each section In ActiveDocument.Sections
        With section.PageSetup
            pageWidth = (.pageWidth) - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin
        End With
        With section.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            .Text = "Left" & vbTab & "Center" & vbTab & "Right"
            With .ParagraphFormat
                .TabStops.ClearAll
                .TabStops.Add pageWidth / 2, Alignment:=WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdCenter
                .TabStops.Add pageWidth, Alignment:=WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdRight
            End With
            .Font.Size = 10
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```